# Tap event not working on html view nativescript

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

In my angular nativescript app I have a list view as shown in the code. Within the stacklayout I call the onItemSelect function on (tap). This tap event seems to work anytime I tap on any part of the screen other than the embedded htmlview. Can someone suggest how I can resolve this.

```
 <ListView [items]="this.searchResults" class="list-group">
        <StackLayout (tap)="onItemSelect(item)">
            <GridLayout rows="auto auto auto auto" columns="1* 14* 3*" >

                <Label [text]=" item.grades" row="0" col="0"
                    colSpan="3"></Label>
                <HtmlView [html]="'<b>'+ item.Text +'</b>'" class="m-x-5" row="1" col="0" colSpan="2"></HtmlView>
                <Image *ngIf="item.ImagesUrl" [src]="item.ImagesUrl" row="1" col="2" rowSpan="3" padding="0" class="img-thumbnail"></Image>
                <StackLayout row="2" col='0' colSpan="3" >
                    <Label [text]="a."></Label>
                   <Label [text]="b."></Label>
                    <Label [text]="c"></Label>
                </StackLayout>

            </GridLayout>
        </StackLayout>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You want the tap to have the same effect when tapping HtmlView than when tapping the rest? You should add a real question in your post.

Comment: I've removed my answer because I have misunderstood your question (My apologies!) - indeed at this very moment, it appears that using HtmlView inside ListView is preventing the event propagation.- issue logged here https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2592